# Message queue for real time chat , ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

How do i create message queuing mechanism for real time chat in asp.net ? At least post some points to start with because for now i'm using synchronous calls to DB for any change.

Comment: @eugeneK You need to implement point-to-point messaging I think ..

Answer (score 0):

An example for you:

[Using TCP/IP](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/TCPIPChat.aspx)